# MS Access Form Validation

Tags: validation, ms-access

I have an Access form that I want to use to update records in a table.  The table may have many instances of one serial number, but only one can be active at a time.  The two fields are IsActive (Boolean) and SerialNumber (Short Text).  I want to prompt the user if they try to create a new record when there is already an active record (IsActive=TRUE) for that serial number. I know I need to use a validation rule, I just have no idea of what the syntax should be.

I tried to use the Expression Builder, but couldn't find anything like my issue.

Comment: No, I don't think ValiditionRule property can handle this. Design a combobox listing only serial numbers that are available. Do you have a table SerialNumbers where serial number is unique?

Comment: Maybe RowSource like: `SELECT SerialNumber FROM SerialNumbers WHERE NOT SerialNumber IN(SELECT SerialNumber FROM othertable WHERE IsActive = True)`